# How do I bind a java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel to a local interface?

Tags: java, multicast

I see some examples that leverage a setOption method on the DatagramChannel class to set the IP_MULTICAST_IF option. However the setOption method does not seem to be present in 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this through the [.setInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html#setInterface%28java.net.InetAddress%29) of the MulticastSocket associated with your channel.

The [.setOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#setOption%28java.net.SocketOption,%20T%29)() on a DatagramChannel is only available since JDK 7.

Answer (score -1):

Use DatagramChannel.open, then channel.setOption(SocketOption.IP_MULTICAST_IF